# Can you somehow use other weapons while dangling from a rope in worms revolution?

Tags: worms-revolution

When I am dangling from a rope some items get greyed out from my inventory, so I assumed the ones that didn't get greyed out could be used from the rope. However, when I selected the dynamite and pressed the fire key, I just disengaged the rope and fell to my death. Am I doing something wrong? Or is it not possible to use other weapons from the ninja rope in the first place?

Comment: You *definitely* can in Worms reloaded... presumably it's the same in revolution, but having not played it I can't answer for sure.

Comment: I seem to recall that the keybind for using a weapon when hanging from a rope is *different* from the standard 'fire weapon' keybind. Possibly the jump key?

Comment: Many thanks LessPop_MoreFizz, I looked in my keybinds and there was another key for dropping items from a rope,jetpack,or parachute. The key was enter by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LessPop_MoreFizz was right in that there is another keybind to drop weapons from a rope (or parachute/jetpack). The key is enter/return by default.